# Python OpenCV error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I run this program and it returns me this error message:

> error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

How can I solve? This is the source code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret,frame = cap.read()


r,h,c,w = 250,90,400,125
track_window = (c,r,w,h)

roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)

        ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

        x,y,w,h = track_window
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)


        cv2.imshow('Rilevamento',img2)

        k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)

    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) `cv2.rectangle` draws a rectangle on the image you gave it in parameter and it doesn't return anything.

Then you just need to change this line :

`cv2.imshow('Rilevamento',img2)`

To

`cv2.imshow('Rilevamento', frame)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it before, and it seems to work but it actually don't catch the area where my face is, my purpose is to detect my face catching it with the rectangle, how can i do that?

Comment: This is not really what you asked... I can't really explain everything but here are links for you to start : [Cascade Classifiers](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html), [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html), [OpenCV Samples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/python2)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain that before, I'll have a look to your links, thank you!